# Python: Tie breaker when sorting a list of tuples (max for first element, and 1st occurrence of the second)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the list I started with

```
names = ["Alice", "Beatrice", "Amarnae", "Zootrope"]
```

The last three items all have 4 vowels each

Created a sorted list based on the count of vowels. Got the one shown below

```
mylist = [(3, 'Alice'), (4, 'Amarnae'), (4, 'Beatrice'), (4, 'Zootrope')]
```

I need to return/find the 1st occurrence of the max quantity

```
print(max(mylist))
```

which returns

```
(4, 'Zootrope')
```

Ask: I need to return as that is the first occurrence of the name in the original list

```
(4, 'Beatrice')
```

I have tried a few different things (incl. `mylist.sort(key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1])` .. but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "I have tried a few different things (incl. mylist.sort(key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1]) .. but doesn't seem to work." That's how it's done. If you have a [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) question, [after taking your own best shot at it first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), show us exactly what code you have, explain what happened and what you expect should happen instead, using a [mre] (in a new question).

Comment: "I need to return as that is the first occurrence of the name in the original list" Python's sort is stable, so the results would naturally be in this order. However, `max` and `sort` are not related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `mylist` is not created with the original item order retained in the first place, hence the issue.

You can use a list comprehension like this to create `mylist`:

```
mylist = [(sum(c in 'aeiou' for c in name.lower()), name) for name in names]
```

which results in the following value for `mylist`, retaining the original item order:

```
[(3, 'Alice'), (4, 'Beatrice'), (4, 'Amarnae'), (4, 'Zootrope')]
```

Since `max` returns the first item with the maximum value, you can then simply use `max` with a `key` function that returns just the first item in the tuple for comparison, since you don't want the lexicographical order of the second item to be taken into account:

```
max(mylist, key=lambda t: t[0])
```

which returns:

```
(4, 'Beatrice')
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/SwelteringFlakyDividend

Comment: thank you @blhsing - really appreciate it. The answer was spot on.